# Adding links inside <% %> code fragment in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, hyperlink

I have written a JSP page (profile.jsp) and I want to go to a link whenever some condition is satisfied(inside if statement).
But, whenever I am using the  tag (Inside <%...%>) to link a webpage its giving me compile error ?
e.g,
<%  [Google](http://www.google.com)  %>

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use response.sendRedirect method
You might check this, this may help.

```
 <%
   //SAMPLE CODE  
    boolean userSubmittedForm = true; 
    if( userSubmittedForm )            //sample condition
        response.sendRedirect("https://www.example.com");
   %>
```